# Where can I find resources about lingua scinter?

Tags: auxlangs, resource-request

> The Lingua scinter is an ideolanguage created in 1931 by Gaetano Viveros. It is the abbreviation for "International scientific lingua based on Latin and Greek". [www.europalingua.eu](http://www.europalingua.eu/ideopedia/index.php5?title=Lingua_scinter)

Here is the only thing I found about this language.

Are there examples, grammar, vocabulary or any other document on the Internet?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention this (50$!) book on [www.iberlibro.com](https://www.iberlibro.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30601897862&searchurl=kn%3DLingua%2Bscinter%255C%26sortby%3D17&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title1) "Elements of GRAMMAR for INTERNATIONAL SCIENTIFIC LANGUAGE. Part 1 (only, but ALL PUBLISHED:) INTRODUCTION and PHONETICS."

With the following description:

> In the first 13 pages, historical notes on the attempts of universal languages (Esperanto, Volapük, Universal, Romanal, Novual, Occidental, Panlingua, Romano-Germanic), with a lot of space to the Congress of Linguists in Geneva (1931), and to Giuseppe PEANO's INTERLINGUA, which he takes as the basic idea to define the rules of the SCINTER LANGUAGE (SCIentific INTERnational): preliminaries for the formation of words and prephrases by means of the Latin vocabulary, and phonetics. Finally, the definition of the concept "grammar".